# Split linear-gradient into an object

Tags: javascript, css, object, split, linear-gradients

I want to split `linear-gradient` value into a `object` with key and value.

I have this:

```
linear-gradient(10deg,#111,rgba(111,111,11,0.4),rgba(255,255,25,0.1))
```

And I want it like this:

```
linear-gradient: {
  angle: '10deg',
  color1: '#111',
  color2: 'rgba(111,11,11,0.4)',
  color3: 'rgba(255,255,25,0.1)',
}
```

EDITED: I tried my code without success:

```
var str = 'linear-gradient(10deg,#111,rgba(111,111,11,0.4),rgba(255,255,25,0.1))';
str = str.match("gradient\((.*)\)");
str = str[1].split(',');
console.log( str );
```

Comment: Did you try to extract string between parenthesis and split it by comma?

Comment: Yes, but it breaks when reaches to first rgba value. i tried like this: str.split(',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Regular expression` we can define what parts we want from string.

```
// Define string
var str = 'linear-gradient(to left top, #F0F calc(30% - 6px), hsl(100, 100%, 25%) 75%, yellow)';

// Get string between first ( and last )
str = str.substring(str.indexOf('(') + 1, str.lastIndexOf(')'));

// Finally with regex we can get each parts separatelly
console.log( str.split( /,(?![^(]*\))(?![^"']*["'](?:[^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)/ ) );
```

And output will be:

```
(4) [Array]
  "to left top"
  "#F0F calc(30% - 6px)"
  "hsl(100, 100%, 25%) 75%"
  "yellow"
```